# Using parent hash in a pallet - can't get the raw values from the associated type

Tags: convert

I'm trying to use the parent block hash in my code, but I having trouble getting the raw numeric values.  I can see that `<frame_system::Pallet<T>>::parent_hash()` returns the values inside an associated type, but I want the [u8; 32] data block inside it.

```
let parent_hash : [u8; 32] = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::parent_hash().try_into().unwrap();
```

which gives me:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8; 32]: std::convert::From<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>` is not satisfied
    |
447 |             let parent_hash : [u8; 32] = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::parent_hash().try_into().unwrap();
    |                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>` is not implemented for `[u8; 32]`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<[u8; 32]>` for `<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>` for `[u8; 32]`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::TryInto<[u8; 32]>` for `<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash`
help: consider introducing a `where` bound, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
53  | impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> where [u8; 32]: std::convert::From<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash> {
    |                           +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And this:

```
let parent_hash : [u8; 32] = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::parent_hash() as [u8; 32];
```

which gives:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash` as `[u8; 32]`
    |
447 |             let parent_hash : [u8; 32] = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::parent_hash() as [u8; 32];
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

What's the correct way to do this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the `Hash` type for a particular chain will be 32 bytes, just because it may be for your specific runtime that type is generic. [These](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L251-L266) are the only assumptions you can make about the `Hash` type. Alternatively you can convert it to a slice of bytes like:

```
let parent_hash: &[u8] = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::parent_hash().as_ref();
```

Comment: Thanks André.  I hadn't realised they were variable length - good to know.  If I'm not worried about over/underflow, is there a way I can then force it into a [u8; 32], please?  I'll need to find a better option later, but I'm just prototyping at the moment, and it's not a major concern.  Alternatively, is there an easy way I can add 1 to the hash value in place? (I realise that's isn't normally something you'd want to do with a hash...)

Comment: Ah! I've found a way I can use the hash as reference for my needs which doesn't care how long the hash is and doesn't require me to increment it!  Thanks for the very useful answer which got me there.